# Facebook blocking content

Tags: facebook

When trying to share informational content on Facebook, I find that it's getting blocked. I get the following error message:

> The content you're trying to share includes a link that our security
>   systems detected to be unsafe:
>   `http://example.com/motorcycle-guides`. Please remove this
>   link to continue.

Does anyone know why this is occurring, and how can I fix it (if possible)?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, since this question is not about a website under your control, it's considered [off-topic](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please feel free to ask questions here in the future that fall within the guidelines of this site.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to contact Facebook via the "Report a problem" link on the logout menu (right side drop down menu).

Facebook flags URLs rather liberally in an attempt to curb spam. As a result, many legitimate links can get blocked rather easily. There's not much you can do short of trying to get the URL whitelisted.